# Динамические массивы C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть код:

```
int* nums = new int[3]();  
nums[7] = 1; // добавим 8й элемент в массив
```

Вопрос почему это работает?
Ведь инициализировали массив из трёх элементов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компилятор никак не контролирует к каким элементам вы обращаетесь. При обращении к массиву `nums[7]` во время выполнения просто рассчитывается смещение до этого элемента массива и туда кладутся данные. При этом эти данные могут попасть на любой объект лежащий в памяти за данным массивом. Так что поведение программы допустившей такое обращение абсолютно не предсказуемо.

"C" позволяет работать с оперативной памятью напрямую, никак не скрывая от программиста эту работу, это его большой плюс по сравнению с другими языками, именно поэтому он используется для написания кода операционных систем (собственно для этого он и был создан). Но это же накладывает ответственность на программиста за его действия.

Comment: Ясно. Не подскажете как увеличивать размер динамического массива `nums`?

Comment: если у Вас с++ и Вам нужен динамический массив - используйте std::vector.

Comment: Хм. Если бы вы его создавали его с использованием malloc, то я бы сказал, что стоит использовать realloc. Но вот что делать с объектом, который создан с помощью new ... посмотрел, википедия говорит что это невозможно, только выделять новую область и копировать. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: realloc и std::vector как раз выделяют новую область, копируют туда всю текущую область и возвращают управление. Просто это все спрятано под капотом.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде **UB**

> В соответствии со стандартами C и C++, если выполнение программы приводит к переполнению знаковой целой переменной, или к любому из сотен других «неопределённых действий» (undefined behaviour, UB), то результат выполнения программы может быть любым: она может запостить на Твиттер непристойности, может отформатировать вам диск…
>   (с) хабра-пост

а именно "**обращение к участку памяти, которая вам не принадлежит**"

то, что у вас скомпилировалось и не произошло, что-то страшное - это удача не более того. К тому же можно предположить, что вы компилируете в debug версии и там шанс схватить крит меньше.

```
   nums[7] = 1; // добавим 8й элемент в массив`
```

кстати данный код делает не добавление, а:
к адрессу nums прибавляется 7 умноженное на размера типа nums ( sizeof(int) ) и в тот адрес записывается 1.

Answer (score 1):

Данный фрагмент кода имеет неопределенное поведение, поэтому последствия выполнения этого фрагмента кода могут быть любыми. Соответствующая программа может завершиться аварийно, либо переписать не принадлежащую массиву память.

Почему это может работать?

Например, может оказаться так, что память, адресуемая выражением

```
nums[7]
```

которое имеет значение адреса, соответствующий значению

```
( char * )nums + 7 * sizeof( int )
```

уже принадлежит вашей программе за счет того, что ранее уже выделялась динамически память для программы именно в этом диапазоне адресов. А потому программа продолжает работать, хотя делает не корректные операции.

Другой пример заключается в том, что обычно когда вы запрашиваете память малого объема, например, размером 4 байта

```
int *p = new int;
```

то на самом деле система выделяет память большего размера. Обычно этот размер равен размеру параграфа, то есть 16 байтам, а, возможно, что на некоторых системах этот размер будет даже больше. В этом случае вы можете писать в эту память без существенных последствий для программы вцелом.

Но в любом случае, как я в начале написал, это ведет к неопределенному поведению программы.